# Missing some Methods when change from NSString to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Hey everybody :) i have one method, which cuts a long text after a given number of words. It looks like this:

```
NSString *trimString(NSString *string, int length, Boolean soft) {
if(string == Nil || string.length == 0){
    return string;
}

NSMutableString *sb = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
int actualLength = length - 3;
if(string.length > actualLength){
    // -3 because we add 3 dots at the end. Returned string length has to be length including the dots.
    if(!soft) {
        [sb appendString:[string substringToIndex:actualLength - 3]];
        [sb appendString:@"..."];
        return sb;
    } else {
        NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, actualLength);
        //NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch range:r];
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \n\r\t"] options:NSBackwardsSearch range:r];
        [sb appendString:[string substringToIndex:range.location]];
        [sb appendString:@"..."];
        return sb;
    }
}
return string;
}
```

My Problem is that i have to change everything to NSAttributedString, but there are no things like "substringToIndex:" so that i can change it....
Is it even possible to change it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use NSMutableAttributedString *attStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: string];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything to an NSAttributedString that NSString supports by referencing the `string` property on the attributed string. This is the underlying NSString that you may do whatever you like with.

Comment: But to remember that the string property, doesn't have the attributes from the NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for string clipping (`substringToIndex:`) you can use:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedSubstringFromRange:(NSRange)aRange
```

Create the proper range and that will give you the functionality you are "missing".

[Source.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/attributedSubstringFromRange%3a)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're working with an NSMutableAttributedString, you need to call your function on NSAttributedString's string property, and you can use the returned string as a parameter to `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:`

If I were you, I would change the prototype of the function to return an NSRange value, this way you could use it in a more general way with strings and AttributedStrings (with functions such as `stringWithRange`)

Comment: *cough* `mutableString`, if he wants to mutate it. Attributes will be handled correctly.